# How to reference to a class used in templateurl?

Tags: angular, typescript, web

I'm using angular on a project and I have a component which is a form consisting of a number of inputs. I've implemented these inputs separately in their own unique component and in each of these components is a function which returns the data given by user. it looks like this:

```
  <mat-card>
    <app-phone></app-phone>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card>
    <app-address></app-address>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card>
    <app-city></app-city>
  </mat-card>
```

I want to use these classes in my typescript file in a way that retrieve the data with their functions.
I've already tried including these classes in constructor but it didn't work.
is this a proper way to make general components? and if so, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of accessing child component methods, you could do it using Reactive  forms approach:

Create a `formGroup` in your parent class say

parent.ts

`parentForm : FormGroup`

and then pass it as an `input` to each of those `child` components. So you have to create

app-address.ts, app-phone.ts ....

`@Input() formGroup : FormGroup`

in each of the child components. You could also create another `@Input formControlName : string` in each child component, and then pass respective `form control name` as an input string to each of those child `component` from parent. With this you can manipulate the entire `form` within your parent component itself, without being worried about child component methods.

```
<mat-card>
    <app-phone [formGroup]="parentForm" [formControlName]="'phone'"></app-phone>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card>
    <app-address [formGroup]="parentForm" [formControlName]="'address'"></app-address>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

`@ViewChild` may help in your case.We can create Object of Child components in the Parent component. Check Angular docs for more help https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#viewchild.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use reactive forms
2. Have your `phone, address, city` components implement 2 interfaces: `ControlValueAccessor` and `Validator`
3. With that you'll be able to use them in reactive forms just as any other form element (input text, for example). This interface gives you what you refer to as ' function which returns the data' but with reactive forms and these interfaces you'll have that wired up  nicely and will work out of the box.

Once you wire it all up in this way you can subscribe to whole form value changes (including your custom components) and your life will be so much easier than maintaining it all by yourself.

Its a bit too much to put it all together but if you goolgle for `ControlValueAccessor example` you'll find a bunch of examples how to implement it.